# Which Product to Use for Repairing My Drywall

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

Can someone recommend which product I should use in this case?... I removed the backsplash tile in my kitchen and, in doing so, some of the tiles also pulled the top layer of drywall off along with the glue adhesive, resulting in patches of the exposed brown paper layer of the drywall.

I read online to seal those areas with a product that would coat it while preventing it from bubbling up, and prevent it from anything water-based that would cause it to bubble up. So I have done that. But now I need to even out the wall before installing new tile. Should I use joint compound, drywall mud {are those the same thing?}, spackle, a Sherwin Williams product mentioned in an answer to a question on this site about drywall repair, general purpose compound, etc.?

There seem to be a lot of products that work similarly, but I want to use what would be best and most stable/sturdy for this situation.

Basically, I have lots of patches that are significantly lower {or deeper} than the areas where the top drywall layer did not come off, because between the thickness in the top layer of drywall and the paint that had previously been on the drywall, together, those two layers create quite a height difference between the torn drywall patches and the rest of the wall where the drywall remained in tact.

I need to even everything out {or make it a flat surface}, and I am wondering what the best product would be to fill the patches up to be level with the good layer of the wall and even up all the areas for a relatively flat surface that my new tiles can lay flat on. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd cut away the bad drywall and replace it with 1/2" hardi board. That'll give a flat, solid and waterproof substrate for your tiles, in contrast to the beaten up drywall you've got now.

Oh, and be sure to thoroughly caulk the gap between the drywall and the hardi.

Comment: Thanks. Not familiar with hardi, so I will have to look that up.

Answer (score 0):

I used drywall paper tape with a couple layers of setting drywall compound (aka 'hot mud', but my application was in a closet, and didn't have the complexity of a wet installation or tiles pulling on my patch.

Even so, it seems about as solid as the rest of the wall, and seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks. I would think/hope that if I use a new tile that is part of a mesh, where several tiles are glued on to one square mesh for easier spacing, and if each tile is small enough to not cause heavy pull or large enough where it wouldn't matter because it's also covering a large area of the good part of the wall, then the pulling factor would not be an issue. If so, I think using the compound would be a good solution. I've actually already applied it just now, and will sand for a smoother and more even finish when it dries.

But I'm wondering how flat it needs to be when adding new tile.